# type = interface1 or interface2 , can't make it work

Tags: typescript

Sorry if this question has been already asked, but I only see "what is the difference between interface and type".

So my problem is I'm created a type which say it can be one object/interface or another. A function received it a parameters with this type and it creates a type problem. It's not easy to explain, so a code will be better :
[go to Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQN4CgoFRwBcUqwCAlgHYDmA3LgL5QA+O+hARqeVXY0JQAxqWoBXZFwgJGTXLgBm46sOCUA9tSjAI5ABRhEKVKXhI0ASg5DKiqIeNoAdHCgBCDFhUATCIpoIH2s8ISFhLVQNABsIZ2iNWn0AIgBJKAB3OGpgHQ0ocVRoN2AACxkIZIAaKCMLVFdLTgIWCGiimzCCCOoo2PjElI0ymQzKDspc5AhsqC4iah8RIgRigDc4Smi4Lljq2qcGrhq6k2dhJqF5eVxdA2wiUmSNAGtkqCYmu+B9B-mn177YRQUgARgAzOCAOwfSxAA).

I don't understand why my variable aren't reachable with this condition, I even tried to use a type guard but I can't make it work.

```
type Params = {
    a: string;
} | {
    b: string;
    c: number;
}

function test(params: Params) {
    if (params.a !== undefined) {
        console.log("I want to use a there", params.a)
    } else {
        console.log("otherwise it mean b and c are available", params.b, params.c)
    }
}

test({ a: "ok" })
test({ b : "ok", c : 1337 })
```

Thanks by advance ;)

Comment: Put a [mre] *in the question*.

Comment: I put a playground link just avoid copying a lot of code but ok, it's done

Comment: [Edit] the question, code in comments isn't very helpful.

Comment: sorry for that :(

Comment: thanks for your time as well jonrsharpe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a type guard for type narrowing. That is because from your union type `Params`, it is possible that `params.a` actually does not exist and is not even accessible. You will find that attempts to access `params.b` or `params.c` will give you exactly the same error.

The type guard should be `'a' in params`, so that TypeScript can narrow the type on `params` automatically and infer that, if this condition is satisfied, then `params` must be of type `{ a: string }`, otherwise, it must be of type `{ b: string; c: number; }`:

```
function test(params: Params) {
    if ('a' in params) {
        console.log("I want to use a there", params.a)
    } else {
        console.log("otherwise it mean b and c are available", params.b, params.c)
    }
}
```

[See proof-of-concept example on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=29#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQN4CgoFRwBcUqwCAlgHYDmA3LgL5QA%20O%20hARqeVXY0JQAxqWoBXZFwgJGTXLgBm46sOCUA9tSjAI5ABRhEKVKXhI0ASg5DKiqPoDkcR1BpQjF1NbxChwrVQNABsIADpgjVp9ACIASSgAdzhqYB0NKHFUaDgdAAsZCBiAGg9jNDC4S04CFghg7Js-AgDqINCIqNiNYAKERMpGyjTkCBSoLiJqABMRIgQcgDc4SmC4LlCSsq8wrlLPEzDhaqF5eVxdA2wiUhiNAGsYqCZqy%20B9a8nbh63hKFIAIwAZiBAHZnpYgA).

---

TypeScript supports 3 different types of type guards:

- [`x in y`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator)
- [`x instanceof y`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards)
- [`x typeof y`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards)

Comment: Awesome thanks ! It perfectly works, thanks you again for your time

Comment: @Exayy No problem! :) when I first dabbled in TypeScript things like this also confuse me all the time. Glad to be of help!